# View popup from a button when pressed and cover the whole window size

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, popup

i am doing coding in iPhone and i want to know how a new view popup from a button when we click it and the popup view continuosly zooming to cover the whole iphone screen.(it is not any image , it is a view having view controllers too)

Answer (score 0):

Your primary view controller should "present" the modal one using `presentModalViewController:animated:`. [(Docs link)](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentModalViewController:animated:)